# Android radio button text truncated

Tags: android

I have an app that shows a Radio Group with four Radio Buttons whose test is set dynamically. I am no able to get the whole text on a single line.

It gets wrapped on two lines, or truncated at the end. It seems like there is a vertical edge, and text cannot go over it.

My layout is

```
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="vds.quizmanager.QuizManagerActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:text="Domanda:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:text="Domanda" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK then you can try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:text="Domanda:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="sdfsgdshfdgsasRFAGRESTDGHFSAFAWhtjygukjtyhergwrqTQETWRYJETRHEWRQEJTUKRYJTRHEAWRWetjyurrutjretwrtjyeukyriu" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
             android:text="Domandaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:text="Domanda" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain my problem well. The text on top ("Domanda:") is working fine. But when I try to set the text to be displayed on right of each Radio Button, it gets truncated.

Comment: I edited with a new code. Tell me if that's what you expect :)

Comment: please if the answer satisfies your question the marque remarries as acceptable :)

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to stack overflow, and not English mother tongue. What do you mean by "marque remarries"?